# php header redirect not working properly

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect

for some reason, some people/browsers redirect to the wrong page. They get sent to:

http://www.site.com/page.php/http://www.site.com/page.php

instead of:

http://www.site.com/page.php

why is this?

Ps. Im using MOD_REWRITE. Would this make a difference?

redirect function:

```
function KT_redir($url) {
    $protocol = "http://";
    $server_name = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
    if ($server_name != '') {
        $protocol = "http://";
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on")) {
            $protocol = "https://";
        }
        if (preg_match("#^/#", $url)) {
            $url = $protocol.$server_name.$url;
        } else if (!preg_match("#^[a-z]+://#", $url)) {
            $script = KT_getPHP_SELF();
            if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) && $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] != '' && $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) {
                $script = substr($script, 0, strlen($script) - strlen($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']));
            }
            $url = $protocol.$server_name.(preg_replace("#/[^/]*$#", "/", $script)).$url;
        }
        $url = str_replace(" ","%20",$url);
        if (KT_is_ajax_request()) {
            header("Kt_location: ".$url);
            echo "Redirecting to: " . $url;
        } else {
            header("Location: ".$url);
        }
    }
    exit;
}
```

MOD_REWRITE

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Give us your code.  We can't debug without it.

Comment: Show us the contents of your .htaccess file with regard to the rewrite part.

Comment: Im using a dreamweaver extension which has a billion functions that control this
:

Answer (score 0):

Before your `else if (!preg_match)`, you need to add a else if check to see if the `$url` begins with a `http` and if so, don't append anything.